# Import own native shared library from sub-module in Android Studio / CMake

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cmake

I have a Android Studio (2.3) project with 2 modules, using CMake for native code.

```
Project
  --> Module1 (app): java + native JNI-wrapper, linking to libnative.so
  --> Module2 (libnative): native c++ code, producing libnative.so
```

What is the preferred way to link `libnative.so` (build by Module2) into the JNI-wrapper in Module1? I currently use...

*Module1-CMakeLists.txt:*

```
add_library( native SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( jniwrapper PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libnative/build/intermediates/cmake/${BUILD_TYPE}/obj/${ANDROID_ABI}/libnative.so )
```

...where `BUILD_TYPE` is set in Module1's `build.gradle`, depending on the build type.

This works if I use "*Make Module 'Module2'*" in AS before building the full project. However, it seems rather inelegant to fetch the library out of gradle's building folder-hierarchy.

The alternative seemed to be to instruct Module2's `CMakeLists.txt` to install the file into Module1's lib-directory and import from there. But CMake seems to ignore the `install` command.

(I'm aware that I could just put the modules together under one tree.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is as below: (Module2 `CMakeLists.txt`)

```
set_target_properties(${SHARED_LIBRARY_NAME}
                  PROPERTIES
                  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "<your-prefered-directory>/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}")
```